What is Carnap’s “Principle of Tolerance”, and how did Quine reject it?

Carnap’s Principle of Tolerance and Quine’s Objections
Carnap holds that the role of philosophy is to analyze and clarify the language of
science, and to formulate and recommend alternative languages. After
1932, he holds that there are languages which differ in expressive
power, not merely as notational variants. The difference between
intuitionistic logic and classical logic is an important example here,
as is the difference between the language of Newtonian mechanics and
the language of relativistic mechanics. (Earlier, he says, he had
‘overlooked the fact that there is a multiplicity of possible
languages’, Carnap 1934, 245; cf. also 322 of the same work.) Within a
given language, there may be only one correct theory on a given
subject. But the choice of a language is in that respect unlike the
choice of a theory. (1): In deciding which theory is correct, we will
appeal to observations but also to the rules of the language; no such
appeal is possible when we are choosing a language, for in this case
it is the rules themselves that we are choosing. So Carnap holds that
there is no one correct language. This idea has become known as the
Principle of Tolerance; from the 1930s on, it is fundamental to
Carnap’s view of what philosophy is and how it differs from science. (That there is such a difference is a point which Carnap never questions.) Because there is no one correct language, it is no part of
the philosopher’s job to prescribe this or that language, merely to
analyze, to clarify, and to suggest alternatives.
(2): The Principle of Tolerance requires the analytic-synthetic
distinction. It requires that we can, in all cases, distinguish
between theoretical changes which involve a change of meaning, and
hence, strictly speaking, a change of language, and those which do
not. The former kind of change involves analytic sentences, and is a
matter for Tolerance; the latter involves only synthetic sentences,
and Tolerance does not apply. The use of the Principle of Tolerance
thus presupposes a clear distinction between the analytic sentences of
the language and its synthetic sentences.
At least as Quine sees the matter, the use of the Principle of
Tolerance puts analytic sentences on an entirely different
epistemological footing from synthetic sentences. Synthetic sentences
are answerable to evidence; analytic sentences are a matter of the
choice of language, which does not require theoretical justification.
(3): Quine, however, rejects the idea that there is such an epistemological
difference. Even if we can distinguish the analytic sentences from the
synthetic sentences, we may still have reasons to reject an analytic
sentence. And those reasons may be of the same kind that lead us to
reject synthetic sentences. This point is hard to see if one focuses
on examples such as “All bachelors are unmarried”. The matter is
otherwise if one considers examples such as “Force equals mass times
acceleration”. (See Putnam, 1962.) A change of mind about an analytic
sentence would be a change in the language. Still, we might have
reasons to make such a change, reasons that are of the same sort that
lead us to make revisions to synthetic sentences. In that case, we
have no more reason to apply Tolerance in the one kind of case than in
the other.
This is the view that Quine argues for. On the one hand, he emphasizes
the point (which Carnap largely accepts) that choice of language is
not theoretically neutral: some choices will make for a better theory
than others. On the other hand, he argues that ‘pragmatic’ factors,
such as simplicity, which Carnap had accepted as playing a role in
choice of language, also play a role in the choice of a theory within
a language. Hence, he claims, the two sorts of choice are on the same
epistemological footing, and the Principle of Tolerance is
unjustified.
(4): Quine’s argument for this position relies on holism. This is the claim
that most of our sentences do not have implications for experience
when they are taken one-by-one, each in isolation from the others.
What has experiential implication is, in most cases, not an individual
sentence but a larger chunk of theory. Holism is not a very
controversial doctrine. (Carnap accepts it; see Carnap, 1934, 318.)
Quine claims that holism shows that most of our sentences are not
justified by the relation of the individual sentence, considered in
isolation, to experience. Almost always, what matters is the relation
to experience of some larger chunk of theory (in principle, although
perhaps never in practice, of the theory as a whole). This means that
in principle the correctness of a given claim is almost never settled
simply by looking at the empirical evidence for that claim alone.
Other factors will play a role, in particular the way in which
accepting the given claim would contribute to the efficacy and
simplicity of the theory as a whole. But these are precisely the
‘pragmatic factors’ which Carnap thought played a role in the choice
of language. In arguing that such factors play a role throughout our
knowledge, Quine accepts ‘a more thorough pragmatism’ (1951, 46) which
puts Carnap’s external changes on the same epistemological footing as
his internal changes. (Quine’s early account of these matters is
extremely sketchy. For elaboration, see Quine 1991 and 1996; for
criticism of the sketchy account, see Sober 2000.)

Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, Willard Van Orman Quine


I suppose I am working up to trying to study “coherentism” from a Quinean perspective, and I’d like a deeper understanding of the above 4 points.

I feel like I need to see a strong example of why Carnap felt “all languages are equivalent”. Didn’t he think there had to be at least some constraints on languages, languages which we hope meaningfully describe the world? Obviously, he probably wasn’t referring to gibberish. Then what was he referring to? How would Carnap defend his view?
This sounds sort of like that “meaning” has two axes, the intensional aspect of logic, where the structures have some kind of “significance” in relation to each other, and the extensional aspect of logic, where those structures correspond to real-world phenomena. So, Carnap believed “devoutly” in the analytic-synthetic divide (like Descartes). But in advocating “tolerance”, what is a concrete repercussion of such an assumption? (For example, does it buttress some kind of epistemological relativism in the social sciences, or “hard” logical pluralism in the philosophy of mathematics?)
Quine rejects the analytic-synthetic divide, but I need far more details why. For example, one might consider logical reasoning itself “empirical”, in that, for any “principles” of reason we hold to be true, we are forced to reject and revise them when they lead to unsound conclusions. Russell’s paradox would be a great example of this: it was not known that there could not be a “set of all sets” until someone discovered a problem with that idea. Thus, “analytic knowledge” is by no means a priori - and since, in a way, we are “observers” of our own thoughts in our own minds, you could claim that even “logical discovery” is a kind of a posteriori, experiential knowledge. Is that why Quine rejects this divide, or something different?
I do not understand (4) at all. Carnap thinks that since that analytic meaning and synthetic meaning are completely orthogonal, it follows that they are independent. Thus, you can choose which “frame” to look at “the world” through, and there is no meaningful way to say which one is “better”; they are just “options”. Quine thinks that the “meaning” of sentences is not just how the language is designed to map to “the real world”, but also very influenced by the intensional characteristics of the language itself. So… since Quine thinks languages “take meaning” in relation to one another, he basically does believe in “one true language” - and that’s “pragmatism”?

#PleaseHelp

See Greg Restall, Carnap's Tolerance Language Change and Logical Pluralism (2001) and Sean Morris, Carnap and Quine: Analyticity, Naturalism, and the Elimination of Metaphysics (2018).

Carnap didn't hold that all languages are "equivalent" (what would that even mean--equivalent with respect to what? Obviously he didn't think all languages were equivalent with respect to their scientific utility, for the entire point of philosophy is to analyze and formulate languages which are better suited for a given scientific purpose).

Rather, his point is that there could be no meaningful propositions which could give a theoretical justification for the use of a language, because all such theoretical/epistemic content presupposes the rules of the language in which the proposition is formulated. So you can't have propositions that justify the choice of linguistic rules. But you can have other pragmatic considerations which justify the choice of a language for a given purpose.

With respect to point (2), no, you're confusing the analytic-synthetic distinction with the difference between intensional and extensional. On point (3), no that's not why Quine rejected it. Quine held that no philosopher has ever succeeded in giving an intelligible account of analyticity, and to the extent that Carnap's conception of analyticity makes sense, it is empty: it has no instances. So either the notion is incoherent or empty.

Your question asks many things and would need a long essay to answer them all. I'll focus on just one.
Quine rejects the concept of analyticity on several grounds. One is that attempts to establish that some sentences are true by virtue of their meanings is either vacuously true or viciously circular. Another is that even sentences identified as analytic by its defenders are not immune to revision in the light of new data. This is perhaps not fatal to the concept of analyticity, but it undercuts the logical positivist project of explaining necessity and a priori knowledge by appeal to analyticity. A third is based on his holism principle. We do not verify or falsify our beliefs individually on a sentence-by-sentence basis, but by testing how entire chunks of beliefs, or theories, fit with our experience. A fourth claim
is that the very concept of 'meaning' is unclear and lacks explanatory value. The latter is part and parcel of Quine's doctrine of the indeterminacy of translation, and follows from his behaviourist approach to linguistics.
To expand the point about holism a little... Suppose we have a theory. We may designate some of the sentences within that theory as axioms, some as definitions and the rest as theorems. But labelling some sentences definitions does not confer any special epistemological status on them. Axioms and definitions are not automatically necessarily true or a priori knowable just because of their status within the theory. The choice of axioms and definitions is made for pragmatic reasons, e.g. for the benefit of clarity and simplicity. The theory as a whole is revisable.
Now suppose we acquire evidence that conflicts with our theory, and a better theory is available. When we replace the old theory with the new one, we are not obliged to retain the old definitions. We might choose to do so, but in some cases it is better to revise the definitions too. Quine and Putnam give an example of this. In classical mechanics momentum is defined to be mass x velocity. Then along comes relativistic mechanics and momentum is redefined to be mass x velocity x Lorentz factor. The change in definition is not arbitrary: the new definition makes a better fit with our superior new theory.
The point is that even definitions themselves are not immune to revision in the light of empirical data, the same as any other propositions are. So if your understanding of 'analytic' is anything like Frege's definition: a proposition that is derivable from a logical truth by substituting definitions, then nothing is immune to revision. Quine is content to allow that sentences like "all bachelors are unmarried men" qualify as analytic in the sense that for a native speaker of a language, that may well be how they learned the meaning of the word 'bachelor'. But how we learned the meaning of words, and what words may come to mean under future scrutiny and criticism can be different things.
Quine's position is developed in a series of papers: Truth by Convention. Two Dogmas of Empiricism. Carnap and Logical Truth. The first few chapters of Word and Object. Also useful is his "Two Dogmas in Retrospect", Canadian Journal of Philosophy, Vol. 21, No. 3, pp 265–74. (1991).
